# Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to rewrite my JS into TS. I have a class called Point2D that is used to manipulate 2 dimensional points. I'm getting an error that `Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)`. What am I doing wrong while moving to TS?

```js
class Point2D {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    public constructor(x: number = 0, y: number = 0) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  
    /**
     * Translate this point by that point
     *
     * @param {Point2D} that
     */
    public add(that: Point2D) {
      return new this.constructor(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y); // ERROR
    }
  
    public subtract(that: Point2D) {
      return new this.constructor(this.x - that.x, this.y - that.y); // ERROR
    }
  
    /**
     *
     * @param {number} scalar
     */
    public multiply(scalar:number) {
      return new this.constructor(this.x * scalar, this.y * scalar); // ERROR
    }
  }
  
  export default Point2D;
```

Comment: this.constructor is a function, you're calling `new` with a function.

Comment: `this.constructor` isn't known to be type safe, since subclasses might have constructors that accept completely different arguments, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2pBjm).  Why not just use `Point2D` instead of `this.constructor`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqeDdm)?  Then it's type safe and the compiler is happy with it.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining fully; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem with your code is that you can [extend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#extends-clauses) a base class with a subclass whose [constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors) doesn't accept the same argument list as the base class.  So `new this.constructor(...args)` isn't known to be safe for any `args`. For example:

```
class StringPoint extends Point2D {
    constructor(x: string, y: string) {
        super(x.trim().length, y.trim().length);
    }
}

const s = new StringPoint("abc", "defgh  ");
console.log(s.x) // 3
console.log(s.y) // 5
```

The `StringPoint` class is derived from `Point2D`, but its constructor accepts two *strings* instead of two numbers.  And it calls these strings' [`trim()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).  So far everything is fine, but when we call one of your base class methods that uses `new this.constructor`, things explode at runtime:

```
console.log(s.multiply(2)) //  ERROR! x.trim is not a function
```

That's because `s.multiply(2)` ends up calling `new this.constructor(6, 10)`, but because `this` is an instance of `StringPoint`, then `this.constructor` is `StringPoint`.  So `new StringPoint(6, 10)` is called, meaning that numbers are passed to something expecting strings, and `number` doesn't have a `trim()` method.  Oops.

---

The correct fix here is probably to just use the `Point2D` constructor directly instead of asking the instance what its constructor was:

```
public add(that: Point2D) {
    return new Point2D(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y); // okay
}

public subtract(that: Point2D) {
    return new Point2D(this.x - that.x, this.y - that.y); // okay
}

public multiply(scalar: number) {
    return new Point2D(this.x * scalar, this.y * scalar); // okay
}
```

That works because `Point2D` is a specific class constructor known to accept two numbers. My `StringPoint` example from above now works without a problem, because the base class methods produce instances of the base class and do not even try to construct new instances of potentially incompatible subclasses:

```
const s = new StringPoint("abc", "defgh  ");
console.log(s.x) // 3
console.log(s.y) // 5
console.log(s.multiply(2)) // okay, {x: 6, y: 10}
```

Here `s.multiply(2)` is a `Point2D` but not a `StringPoint`.

---

Note that the typings for [the `constructor` property of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) in TypeScript are unfortunately not very useful; `this.constructor` is seen as being of the [`Function` or "untyped call" type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function).  This is both too *strict* since there is information you *could* know about the constructor property which is missing from `Function` (as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841)) and too *loose* because, although `new` is rejected, you are allowed to call `Function` with any arguments at all (as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#48284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48284)).

This means that one might decide that the problem would be fixed if you remove the `new` operator and just call `this.constructor(6, 10)` instead of `new this.constructor(6, 10)`.  And while that would indeed stop the compiler from issuing an error, the victory would be short-lived because it would guarantee a runtime error from most JavaScript engines. Calling a `class` constructor without `new` will give you a `TypeError` (see [the relevant portion of the ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist)).

So beware when dealing with the `constructor` property in TypeScript!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5A9jKSDeAoXShS8ANiFFgApoCWwALgEwAiOBRHAHgFxLACuYAEYQATgG52HQgE9eA4WMnSiMfkJI14xNMCj1R-ePTSiAFDz6CRopAF4kABgA0SOVcW2HjgJRsVKvQAFjRQAHSc9kicygEcwaFhMlEysSoAvvhxAPQAVLlSKrlIACqiIHpk9MgJWDC0DEhCycEg9Ej1dPSF0gVxSMUAAnDlYDjUXSzpSK3d-bnZParqmtogACbrZrO8Ewwsfnj9RKIQ9PyiwHwQAO4zIeHwuvqGxqbbDxFIANT3bRGuWpJH5-ehJHziJDZbJIACiACV4Sh4UtCJlUR0VlokFB1AYEPQPm1dg0mMxDhiOKdzpdrncgU89AYjCZzEDIgBaUEA+6JZJc2bgyHQuGI5EY9E5fKUvpxIYjcA4BQ2aZQeAgMiiGWLOJqDTYsD8Ej0GgwEgyMxqjUgUTyaxiCnHQjUi5XYC3XmPZ7Mt5sz6RYpWzWAz7JQPqzUQqEwhFIlFxTIcSVEUjkLAAZQMdAA5nt2hBONVgOsqKSWP4AoyXiz3pYXjnXO568Bs46nbiYGILGEs2AzD4wiQIC3go2e6IaH2B0OR0EIRLComU96cVF3XdMxOW3mzAAiEBCeC71y79YQABm2aChF3844VbQQ8HaGzloifhFAGZCg+nyQX2+MgfjCACshQGMkRyVs8j4QM+r7hIaxqmuaZiMD4fiLsQbTwNeZgQG2Ki-nB-6vgR0ainGACE0TjpOSChHwaDtCASDnvwwDGDQuiLvg6KgJAsAIMgABiNCRFBhCphQSB5uWknSJYypKBi7jKRIGJ6qsOhMq8rIWHanhRC4biGTYxmEf07JRDElJEECyQOKkC66liaybES9AkpM5IVscLq0uusllswHyJJEvyCpwIZ8iCgpAWk0jJioWnYriQj4sYnnefsvkKXEAVuh6cmhdZApBP80WesC5X-AlC6aW5SBISaZoWkGNpmQ6fn9IVdLBT5YXhAGOIRjaMXhGGo3WqId4BEuaJZCmZAyZuOZ5kgBZFiWA25T197enpta8M22aNidWYtpZcQdl2nB0VOg7Dtmo5uA9-ZPbOc0ZLxB1MquDhBWt26knuB5HieZ6XteSC3olxHwW+nDAUg35-VAsGI5NKNgejmOkW+LUoRa6Eo2gADWIAyK42CWAAbOdSAAIyOJk6RAA)